# Fine tuning the ccfonts package

Tags: fonts, packages, computer-modern

A little background the package ccfonts does not have any bold characters hence when you use it it loads the computer modern bold. Now there is an option for this package: "boldsans" when it uses a condensed sans-serif version of computer modern for bold. Now here is what I am after: I want cmbright bold to be used instead. How can I make that happen?

EDIT: I want the bold used in math mode to be cmbright as well!

EDIT-2: Nobody? :(

Comment: Don't be impatient. This board doesn't move that fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard to answer without seeing some examples of your usage.

Here's a guess, though I think it would be at best a kludge. Put this *after* loading `ccfonts`.

```
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\fontfamily{cmbr}\fontseries{bx}\selectfont}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf} {OT1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbold}{OML}{cmbrm}{b}{it}
```

I think there may be better ways, and I'm not really confident this is going to work out well, but without seeing a sample of how you're using bold in your document, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thank you this works and so far I do not have any problems!

Comment: Also could you post the same code that would force the package to use cmbright for sf series, both Math and text? I guess it should be very similar but I don't know the exact syntax.

Comment: For text, I think `\renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{cmbr}` should cover you. Math is trickier, and I'm not sure what the best way to handle it would be. A first guess would be `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}`, but play around with different encodings (`{OML}`, `{OT1}`, `{T1}`, etc.), with `{cmbr}` vs `{cmbrm}` and with different shapes `{it}` vs `{n}`, etc.. until it looks right with no warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like the cmbr fonts so I made myself a boldface using tikz:

```
  \def\dikte{0.2}

    \newcommand{\dik}[1]{\hspace{-1.5pt}\mbox{\!\tikz[baseline=(X.base),text depth=-0cm,text height=0cm,-]{\draw[use as bounding box](0,0)node(X)[,-]{\normalsize#1};
    \foreach\x in{0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315}{
    \draw(0,0)++(\x:\dikte pt)node[,-]{\normalsize#1};}}\!}}
```

not the most elegant way I recon, but it sure does work. I adapted my section, chapter, mathbf, caption, etc commands to use this \dik font

If you want I'll post the Tex file that contains these adaptions